# FFMPEG and AVC-Intra Class 100 1080p 59.94/60p

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I've got FFMPEG making AVC-Intra Class 100 1080i files with no issues.. But when I try to step it up to 1080p, using class 100, it says its not supported. We can create these files out of Adobe Media Encoder..

```
[libx264 @ 0000020f5bc5d7c0] FPS 60/1p not compatible with AVC-Intra
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!

ffmpeg -i "test.mxf" -y -vcodec libx264 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -r 60 -x264-params avcintra-class=100:interlaced=0 -strict unofficial
```

I've added the `-strict unofficial` just to see if i could bypass it to create a file to test with..

[Link to Media Encoder AVC-I 100 1080p 59.94 supported setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siaaz.png)

Not sure if I'm missing a switch or this is just not developed yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-r 60000/1001`, not `-r 60`:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mxf" -y -vcodec libx264 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -r 60 -x264-params avcintra-class=100:interlaced=0 output
```

As shown in your screenshot Adobe Media Encoder is outputting 60000/1001 (named "59.94" which is a truncated nickname), not 60 fps.